# how to add resources to url in python google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url

I'm trying to make a blog/news site and would like to have articles have the url:
`http://mysite.com/2012/02/05/slug/`
My problem is appending the `/2012/02/05/slug/` to the url in python. I can save the date and slug into Gql database, as well as the article's content. I just don't how to add the date and slug resource into the url. Searching google hasn't really worked because I don't know what this technique is called...but know most new/blog sites implement it. Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a general function

```
import urlparse

def url_rev(pubdate, slug):
    return urlparse.urljoin('http://mysite.com',
                            '/%s/%s/%s/%s/'%(pubdate.year, pubdate.month, pubdate.day, slug))
```

But
If you are using [webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/index.html): [`uri_for`](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2.html#webapp2.uri_for)
if you're using [App Engine Patch](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/), you can use Django, including its URL resolvers.
If you are using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) you can use [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for)